# Generalizing Concurrent Map Function with Empty Interface In GOlang

Tags: go, concurrency, mapreduce

So I'm super new to Golang and seeing as the big buzz around the language seems to be concurrency I figured a good way to get my toes wet would be to write a generalized map function. In psudo code:

```
map(F funtion,A array){
    return([F(k) for k in A])
}
```

And obviously I want the calculations for each F(k) occur concurrently. For organization I have a main file with my implementation and a supporting file Mr with my required definitions.

```
.
├── main.go
└── Mr
    └── Mr.go
```

Main is a simple test implementation which should convert an array of strings to an array of ints where each member of the result is the length of the corresponding string in the input array.

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "./Mr"
)

func exfunc(i int, c chan int){
    c<-i
}

func main(){
    data := make(map[int]string)
    data[1]="these"
    data[2]="are"
    data[3]="some"
    data[4]="words"
    data[5]="and a few more..."
    f := func(w string)int{
        return(len(w))
    }
    testMr := Mr.Map(f,data) // this is line 22 (matters later)
    fmt.Println(testMr)
}
```

Which works great with my Mr.Map function given that I specify all the types explicitly.

```
package Mr

type result struct{
    key,value int
}

func wrapper(f func(string) int,k int,v string, c chan result){
    c <- result{k,f(v)}
}

func Map(f func(string) int,m map[int]string) map[int]int{
    c := make(chan result)
    ret := make(map[int]int)
    n := 0
    for k := range m{
        go wrapper(f,k,m[k],c)
        n++
    }
    for ;n>0; {
        r := <-c
        ret[r.key]=r.value
        n--
    }
    return(ret)
}
```

However I was hoping that I would be able to generalize this mapping with the empty interface.

```
package Mr

type T interface{}

type result struct{
    key,value T
}

func wrapper(f func(T) T,k T,v T, c chan result){
    c <- result{k,f(v)}
}

func Map(f func(T) T,m map[T]T) map[T]T{
    c := make(chan result)
    ret := make(map[T]T)
    n := 0
    for k := range m{
        go wrapper(f,k,m[k],c)
        n++
    }
    for ;n>0; {
        r := <-c
        ret[r.key]=r.value
        n--
    }
    return(ret)
}
```

Unfortunately when I run main with this generalize Mr.Map I get the following error.

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:22: cannot use f (type func(string) int) as type func(Mr.T) Mr.T in argument to Mr.Map
./main.go:22: cannot use data (type map[int]string) as type map[Mr.T]Mr.T in argument to Mr.Map
```

So yeah, obviously I understand what the errors are telling me but it seems wild that I would have to re-write my Map function for each possible combination of key and value types.

`Is there a work around here, or is this just the nature of the beast?`

Comment: While your counter will work fine, there is a built-in type to manage this, [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup), worth taking a look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No real workaround there, that's the nature of the beast.

The language was designed after struggling with C++ for some time, and the idea of the creators was simplifying all non-vital things but at the same time make key additions to make the language more expressive.

You can read a bit about their reasoning here, which I believe is quite interesting even if you don't agree with all the decisions they made:

https://commandcenter.blogspot.com.ar/2012/06/less-is-exponentially-more.html

In your example, if you wanted to, you could make your maps and functions use `interface{}` (which by the way is called the empty interface and not "nil" interface).

But of course you would lose compile-time type checking and would have to add casts all around.

You can also try to find an interface to express the commonalities of the types you want to use (which might not be so easy or even possible at all), and then build your mapping API around that interface.

Comment: Well it's not the answer I wanted, but it is what I expected... Also thank you for pointing out what to call the empty interface!

Comment: @kpie: yeah, I imagined... if you have time you can read this thread which shows quite well the philosophy behind not adding precisely this kind of feature to the language: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/RKymTuSCHS0

Comment: Actually I'm not looking for map reduce and filter. That has all allready been created (https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/glow-map-reduce-for-golang/). What I am looking for may lay in unsafe.go (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/unsafe/unsafe.go) but I haven't looked into that thoroughly yet.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that your map-reduce is *less than 20 lines of code*. Writing this each time you need to implement m-r is trivial - I've seen more boilerplate in a Java DTO that does nothing.

Comment: It's trivial but so is everything.

Answer (score 1):

The philosophy of Go is not compatible with generalized functions such as is the style with popular dynamic languages. To properly inform the compiler of what you are trying to do, you should express your needed map through an interface or simply by writing it for each type you are using it with.

Mapping requires allocating an array, iterating through a collection, and adding to the array some data element for each element in the collection. If you need a map for a slice of structs, as is common in the application layer, you can express this tersely in Go:

https://play.golang.org/p/pk3Tl_BdlD

Dynamic languages build a "type tree" of "generic" types that allow for terse programming, such as functions like `map` being called by one symbol over any possible type. This provides a ton of developer productivity because code can be written loosely to allow easy experimentation.

Go is designed for writing semi-permanent software. It performs well because it requires more information to be supplied to the compiler. Map is only about three lines of code, so the cost/benefit of developer productivity v. efficiency lands on the performance side for Go. Functions like map, reduce and filter should be written explicitly as needed.

To evaluate the language, I would encourage you to try to solve a problem with a Go program and see where that takes you.

Comment: Thanks, I've only been programming with Golang for 24 hours so the example is extremely helpful. (I actually hadn't figured out how to append until reading your example.)